# How can I overlay system-tray icon ? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system-tray, trayicon

I've got a window like

```
<Window
  x:Class="Hardcodet.NetDrives.UI.SystemTray.Sample"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">
  <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
      <TaskbarItemInfo>
          <TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay>
              <DrawingImage>
                  ...
              </DrawingImage>
          </TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay>
      </TaskbarItemInfo>
  </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
  <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="myNotifyIcon" Icon="pic.png"/>
</Window>
```

How is it possible to add some DrawingImage on tray icon? I hope there is smth like TaskBarItemInfo,but for tray icon (not for taskbar icon).

Comment: CodeProject has a great article about implementing [WPF systray icon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon), it has many features including setting image sources for the tray icon.

Comment: there is no anything about overlay on tray icon over there